# "Error in strsplit (log, NULL): non-character argument" - Can't plot a scatterplot of a multiple regression

Tags: r, plot, strsplit

I'm trying to create a scatterplot of a multiple regressions model to check assumptions of the test but it seems to come up with the following problem:

> Error in strsplit(log, NULL) : non-character argument

This is the line of code I have tried using:

```
plot(RMS2_data$N, RMS2_data$E, RMS2_data$O, RMS2_data$A, RMS2_data$C, type = 'p', ylab = "Depression", xlab = "Personality Traits", main = "")
```

Could you please advise how I can fix it so I can create the plot?

Comment: `plot` doesn't have so many data arguments. Maybe you want to plot a first vector and then add other vectors to the plot.

Comment: Thanks for helping!! How would you go about adding other vectors in R?

Comment: Maybe functions `matplot` or `lines`. Or `points`, since your plot has `type = "p"`.

Comment: @PiaDeGiorgis Can you provide a sample dataset or public dataset reference? That would help a lot in providing a solution.  The function `dput(RMS2_data) ` is your friend here.